# Friend Function is not able to access private data of class

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, friend

I have been trying to learn about friend functions, but the following problem does not work.

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class item{
        int cost;
        float price;
        public:
        void getData(){ int a;float b;
            cout << "Please enter cost" <<endl;
            cin >> a;
            cout << "Please enter price" <<endl;
            cin >> b;
            cost =a;
            price=b;
        }
        friend void addTheTwo();
    } i1,i2,i3;
    class student{
        int marks;
        public :
        void getData(){
            int a;
            cout << "Please enter marks";
            cin >> a;
            marks=a;
        }
        friend void addTheTwo();
    }s1;
    void addTheTwo(student s1,item i1){
        cout << s1.marks +i1.cost;
    }
    int main(){
    i1.getData();
    s1.getData();
    addTheTwo(s1,i1);
    return 0;
    }
```

This program, however, gives the following error:

```
test10_13_march.cpp: In function ‘void addTheTwo(student, item)’:
test10_13_march.cpp:30:16: error: ‘int student::marks’ is private within this context
   30 |     cout << s1.marks +i1.cost;
      |                ^~~~~
test10_13_march.cpp:19:9: note: declared private here
   19 |     int marks;
      |         ^~~~~
test10_13_march.cpp:30:26: error: ‘int item::cost’ is private within this context
   30 |     cout << s1.marks +i1.cost;
      |                          ^~~~
test10_13_march.cpp:5:9: note: declared private here
    5 |     int cost;
```

Can someone please explain what is the problem with the code?

Comment: You have added `addTheTwo()` as a friend function, however, your function  is `addTheTwo(student,item)`. They are two different functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
friend void addTheTwo();
```

makes the function `addTheTwo` taking **no parameter** a friend function of the class. But you defined another one! C++ lets you define overloaded function, same name but list of args different (so different functions). Thus:

```
void addTheTwo(student s1,item i1) {...}
```

defines another function that is not friend... Change the friend definition to:

```
friend void addTheTwo(student s1,item i1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the `friend` declaration needs to match that of the referenced function. That is, this

```
friend void addTheTwo();
```

say that the 0-ary function `addTheTwo` is a friend, whereas this

```
void addTheTwo(student s1,item i1){
    cout << s1.marks +i1.cost;
}
```

is an unrelated 2-argument function. Replace your `friend` declarations with

```
friend void addTheTwo(student, item);
```

Answer (score -1):

Like the compiler says, you have marks declared as private within the student class.

try this:

```
class student {
  public:
   int marks;
  private:
   // rest of class
};
```

Comment: I think it voids the purpose of having `private` data members. Also then, the friend declaration will be useless too.

Comment: it'd more useful of me to let you know that the attributes and methods of a class are private by default. (in a struct they're public). So you have to explicitly declare them as public using that keyword as illustrated.

Comment: @avinal you're right - good design uses private attributes, but that wasn't the question posed by the OP.

Comment: you and @avinal are wrong and clearly do not understand the concept of friend functions/classes.

Comment: I do, but I remember when I was learning friend functions/classes, and although the answer by @VorpalSword is perfectly correct, It will probably not help the motive of the person. :)

Comment: @avinal:this answer is not wrong but ill advised. friend functions/classes used judiciously solves problems that otherwise be imposible or very hard to solve.

Comment: @engf-010 - that’s a bold and, incidentally, counter factual claim. Please provide your evidence here.

Comment: if your answer was any good ,it wouldn't be downvoted (which incidentally I didn't do ,out of principle I never downvote). What facts are you factually countering how ? If you want to be educated about befriending (which you obviously need) ,you must do your own research or ask a question here on SO (topic is to broad to be explained in a comment).

Comment: @engf-010 that’s not how logic works. You accused me of not understanding the concept of friendship in c++. Where’s your evidence? You’ve provided nothing so far. If you think I don’t understand `friend` say why. My answer isn’t a good start because it just gets the OP past their first (of likely many) compiler errors.